# React Native Router Flux componentDidMount Fires in the Wrong Component

Tags: react-native

I have an alert to fire on a component's componentDitMount which is NOT an initial route (MainHome in this case). But when another component that is initial (MySchedule) is loaded it displays the alert. The routes are:

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Router createReducer={reducerCreate}>
            <Scene key="modal" component={Modal} >
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
                    <Scene key="tabbar" component={NavigationDrawer}>
                        <Scene key="main" tabs={true} default="tab2" >
                            <Scene key="my_schedule" component={MySchedule} hideTabBar={true} navBar={NavBar} initial={true} />
                            <Scene key="intro" component={Initial} hideTabBar={true} navBar={NavBar} />
                            <Scene key="home" component={Home} hideTabBar={true} navBar={NavBar} />
                            <Scene key="main_home" component={MainHome} hideTabBar={true} navBar={NavBar} />
                        </Scene>
                    </Scene>
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="error" component={Error}/>
            </Scene>
        </Router>;
    }
}
```

And in the component MainHome's componentDidMount the alert is fired.

```
componentDidMount() {
    Alert.alert(
        '“Welcome...',
        [
            {text: 'OK'}
        ]
    );
}
```

So in the initial component (MySchedule in this case) should not display the alert but it does and I can't figure out why. Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how NavigationView works.

```
 <View
    style={this.props.style}>
    {this.props.navigationState.children.map(this._renderScene)}
  </View>
```

NavigationExperimental is changing a lot, so this could change.

See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6579